# The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>)

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, webusercontrol

I have a web user control:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="SitewideNotification.ascx.cs" Inherits="Controls_Fresh_SitewideNotification" %>

<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="Javascript">
    test
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

In my code behind I have:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.Master.FindControl("JSContent").Controls.Add(Javascript);
}
```

My master page ends with:

```
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="JSContent"/>

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

But I get the error:

```
System.Web.HttpException: The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).

Page.Master.FindControl("JSContent").Controls.Add(Javascript);
```

I'm a bit lost as to why this is, does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Which is the part of your code that contains the `<% %>` tags? Can you work around having these in your page. I've had this issue before...

Comment: @ElRonnoco I don't know which part contains the `<%%>` tags, I can't find any.  The code I've shown above is how it is.

Comment: That's strange, I think there must be some in there! Or maybe they are in a master page?

Comment: @Elronnoco the master page has a lot of stuff on it, but the control I'm adding to is just as above `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="JSContent"/>`  I've tested that the webusercontrol is finding the control to add to OK, and it is.  It's just refusing to actually add to it.

Comment: Try to group and wrap the constructs with an <asp:PlaceHolder

Comment: @Adrian, tried wrapping everything with Placeholders but same error still occurs

Comment: Is the only Control you are trying to add the `Javascript` one?

Answer (score 0):

I have usually seen this when I have javascript code with the <% %> block in the head section of the page.  When you move it out of the head to below the body it seems to go away in the situations I have seen.  Since you didn't show us that part of the code it is going to be hard to say exactly what the issue is but here is a good post on the problem:

http://leedumond.com/blog/the-controls-collection-cannot-be-modified-because-the-control-contains-code-blocks/

Comment: If I completely remove the `<head>` tag from my master page, the same error still persists.

Comment: In that case we need to see the layout and especially the portion of the javascript code that contains the <% %> tags

Comment: here's the entire master page: http://pastebin.com/nzvX6wDA The control is on line 22, the control I'm trying to add to on line 251